# PHP Password Verification w/ BCrypt

Tags: php, passwords, verification, bcrypt

I'm having some problems with my user authentication system, what am I doing wrong?

I'm trying to query the database for a password stored on there, check if the password on the database is the same as the one entered on the login page and then I'll add functionality from there.

But it just doesn't work. It repeatedly fails and prints out "Sorry, try again."

**login.php**

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$userpass = $_POST['password'];

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$getpass = "SELECT password FROM users WHERE email = $email";
$hash = mysqli_query($conn, $getpass);


if(password_verify($userpass, $hash)) {
    echo "You're in.";
} else {
    echo "Sorry, try again.";
}
```

**register.php**

```
 // Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) 
{
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully <br>";

$email = $_POST['email'];
$userpass = $_POST['password'];

$options = [
    'cost' => 12,
];

$hash = password_hash($userpass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);

$register = "INSERT INTO users (registered_on, email, password) VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '$email','$hash')";

if ($conn->query($register) === TRUE)
{
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else 
{
    echo "Error: " . $register . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

// Closes connection
$conn->close();
```

I have a hunch it is to do with how I am querying the database.

note from comment: The [password_verify](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) function is a built-in PHP function

Comment: Or what you're trying to verify... It looks like you're trying to verify the entire hash returned from the query rather than the password value...  try changing to     if(password_verify($userpass, $hash["password"])) {

Comment: I assumed I couldn't with BCrypt, because its one way. I think that may be my major flaw, maybe I should move to another algorithm.

Comment: Check what value `$hash` contains after the database call in *login.php*. Is it the same `password_hash()` produced? If not, investigate why not. If yes, post an (made up) example of a password and a hash that fail in `password_verify()`.

Comment: The password_verify function is a built-in PHP function, I didn't write it.

Comment: I'm having problems getting any sort of hash back from the database from that query, it just won't echo anything.

Comment: Then you need to investigate why the DB call is not returning the hash. Start by checking the table record content with some DB administration tool.

Answer (score 1):

You miss quotes around the email here:

```
$getpass = "SELECT password FROM users WHERE email = '$email'";
```

hence your query not returning a hash, and the password_verify not able to verify the password

you can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14123649/576767) for greater details about quotes

**As a very important side-note**, I encourage you to carefully read [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/576767) on how to prevent sql injection as your code seem to be pretty injectable.

Please understand that using mysqli in itself is not a protection against injection, only by using prepared statements and parameterized queries will you be protected.

Comment: Thank you very much. Not only did you point out my silly mistake, you've saved me a hell of a lot of trouble in the future. Thank you.

Comment: My pleasure. And don't be put off by the duplicate mark. Looking onward to your further contributions!